# MongoDB and Mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

How can I improve the performance of updates with MongoDB and Mongoid?  We are seeing writes to MongoDB that take 4 seconds each when we do an update.  The query in mongoid is:

```
Person.where({ name: attributes[:name] })
 .update_all(university: attributes[:university])
```

This is locking (I believe) MongoDB on each write so it isn't like we can do the queries in parallel.  I have tried to look in to adding indexes, but have read that it will actually slow down the updates.

Any ideas on what we can do to improve the performance from 4 seconds?  The only other option that I can think of is sharding, but hoping for something else I haven't been able to find.

thanks
Mike Riley

Comment: How many documents is this updating (and how big is the overall collection)? Indices have some impact on insert speed but unless you have a very high volume of writes that probably isn't much of a factor

Comment: Hey Frederick,  here are the stats:  "count" : 7073915, "size" : 519699536, "avgObjSize" : 497.

Comment: Indexes speed up updates because they make it quick to find the documents that need to be updated. They slow down updates because, if the indexed field is changed, a document moves on disk, or a new document is inserted, the index needs to be updated. The benefits of having an index on the find part of an update almost always greatly outweighs the costs, so try adding an index on `{ "name" : 1 }`.

Comment: Thanks, I am adding an index to that now and will test it out to see how it performs.  I'll let you know how it goes.